# If i have large amount of data, should i create multi data stream instead of a single data stream

Tags: elasticsearch, data-stream

If the storage capacity is about several Trillionbyte, should i use a single data stream?
like this:

data stream aaa, contains index:aaa-2022.01.06-0001,aaa-2022.01.06-0002,aaa-2022.01.07-0003

or several data stream

data stream one: aaa-2022.01.06,constains index:aaa-2022.01.06-2022.01.06-0001

data stream two: aaa-2022.01.07,constains index:aaa-2022.01.07-2022.01.07-0001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the former as data streams are managed by ILM policies and automatically name their underlying indexes with [the index creation date](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/data-streams.html#data-streams-generation) (i.e. `.ds-<data-stream>-<yyyy.MM.dd>-<generation>`), so you wouldn't also add the current date in the data stream name itself.

Just define the adequate ILM policy for your data stream (with proper rollover period and/or size and retention) and you're good.